# How to enable WordLift JSON-LD only for News pages

Tags: wordlift

I have main pages in my site there I just will use my handy-dandy-custom schema but I want to use WL in all my blogPosts/articles and then from there I link to this main pages.

How is possible I remove all WordLift inside my existing pages? (where I already mark some entities) and just use for my news one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following filter:

```
add_filter( 'wl_jsonld_enabled', function( $value ) {

  // You can perform any check you need, e.g. is this the Home page?
  $is_homepage = is_home() || is_front_page();

  // or is this a post?
  $post_id     = is_singular() ? get_the_ID() : null;

  // You can also get for the queried object for further checks.
  $query_object = get_queried_object();

  // Then return true to enable the JSON-LD or false to disable it.
  return $value;
} );
```